# cookie checkbox for what href user was chosen

Tags: javascript, cookies, href

I want to create a 2 button script with a "remember me" checkbox that puts a cookie on the user's browser.
Next time he will enter the site he will be automatically redirected to the link he choose the first time.
I was looking all over for something like this

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Please Choose Your Preference</p>
    <br/>
    <div class="normal_site"><a href="">Regular Site</a></div>
    <div class="mobile_site"><a href="">Mobile Site</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have described the solution correctly: save it in a cookie. What's have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't know how to do this. i am looking for any piece of code/link or advice please

Comment: Save the choice in a cookie in a click handler. On page load, check for the cookie; if it's there, do `window.location.href=cookievalue` to redirect.

Comment: Barmar, i'm kinda new to programming but i can understand code. can you give me a link or somthing i can handle with ? thank you anyway

Comment: Take a look at some of the questions in the Related sidebar, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074254/cookies-to-switch-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (jQuery needed). http://jsfiddle.net/infernalmaster/c6cmk/8/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div id="conteiner">
    <p>Please Choose Your Preference</p>
    <br>
    <div class="normal_site "><a class="sitelink" href="http://www.regular.com/">Regular Site</a></div>
    <div class="mobile_site"><a class="sitelink" href="http://www.mobile.de/">Mobile Site</a></div>
    <div class="remember"><input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" checked=""> Remember My Selection<div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    $(document).on('click', '.sitelink', function(){ // if user click on link
       var site_pref = $(this).attr('href');         
       if($('#remember_me').is(':checked')){        //if checkbox is checked then 
                                                    //  write link url t cookie
          createCookie('site_pref', site_pref, 30);  // for 30 days
       } else {
          eraseCookie('site_pref');                
       }
       return true;
    });


    var site_pref = readCookie('site_pref');  //read cookie
    if(site_pref){                             //if cookie present then
        self.location=(site_pref);      //redirect to path form cookie
    }    
}

validate();

// Taken verbatim from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: rosyyslav, this is not working for me. i used @Barmar code and moderated it. now it's working like i want but o have one last problem, the "if (document.getElementById('remember_me').checked)" is not working properly (not activating the cookie function).  what am i doing wrong ?
see my code here:
http://zeevm.co.il/dror/wp-content/plugins/zeevmobile/mobile-page.php

Comment: I reworked your code and add class="sitelink" to html. Seems works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the full example working here: http://jsfiddle.net/c6cmk/

The most important part of the code is:

```
$('.normal_site').on('click', function() {
    createCookie('site_pref', 'normal', 1);
});
$('.mobile_site').on('click', function() {
    createCookie('site_pref', 'mobile', 1);
});
var pref = readCookie('site_pref');
if (pref) {
    alert(pref);
} else {
    alert('please choose a website!');
}
```

Initially, if the user did not chose anything, it's prompting for him to pick a link. After he clicks either, if he revisits the page (try reloading) he'll get an alert with his previous pick.
Note: the cookie is only stored for 1 day, you might want to increase that.

I'm using jQuery and a few cookie functions taken from [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Comment: that is great, i want the cookie to work only if a checkbox is checked and to redirect to the choosen link automatically next time user is entering the site.  
you helped a lot anyway so i am already grateful

Comment: the code given here dosn't work with recent JQUERY version, i shanged "$" to "jQuery" and now it is :)